# how to display graphs as a tree in python program?

Tags: python, function, graph, tree

Is there any function that can display graphs as a tree in python just like in the picture?
[image: Graph]

I'm new in python and I didn't find a function that can put graphs in the tree.

Comment: [graphviz](graphviz.readthedocs.io/) is quite immediate. PS a graph is not necessarily a tree

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I would like to know the code that allows to display the figure above in python or r